# Is it possible to inject JavaScript into the webview of an already built React-native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, inject

I don't want anyone to inject JavaScript into my apps.
So, if it is possible to do something like the title, I try to write code to prevent this.
But this seems too difficult, so I ask a question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.